# Import many icons from Font Awesome

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, javascript-import

I'm importing many FA icons:

```
import { faUsers, faCut, faBullhorn, faPenNib, faCircle, faPalette, faVolumeUp, faSmile, faGrin, faShekelSign, faTv, faUserTie, faFolder, faPaintBrush, faCircleNotch, faSignOutAlt } 
from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(faUsers, faCut, faBullhorn, faPenNib, faCircle, faPalette, faVolumeUp, faSmile, faGrin, faShekelSign, faTv, faUserTie, faFolder, faPaintBrush, faCircleNotch, faSignOutAlt)
```

How can I declare that list once and then re-use it? Would it be an array? Or an object ... of what?

I was thinking

```
const icons = {faUsers, faCut, faBullhorn, faPenNib, faCircle, faPalette, faVolumeUp, faSmile, faGrin, faShekelSign, faTv, faUserTie, faFolder, faPaintBrush, faCircleNotch, faSignOutAlt}

import icons from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

But of course that doesn't work. And what would I do for `library.add()`?

What is that object-looking thing that follows `import` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to create a new module that exports your specific icons.

```
// icons.js
export {
    faUsers,
    faCut,
    faBullhorn,
    faPenNib,
    faCircle,
    faPalette,
    faVolumeUp,
    faSmile,
    faGrin,
    faShekelSign,
    faTv,
    faUserTie,
    faFolder,
    faPaintBrush,
    faCircleNotch,
    faSignOutAlt
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

Then you can simply import your new module and consume it using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or use it directly.

```
// library.js
import {library} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

import * as icons from './icons';

// using the spread syntax
library.add(...Object.values(icons));

// or using the variable directly 
library.add(icons);
```

Comment: You can just call `library.add(icons)` here and it should work.

Comment: Now we know you can use the variable directly, why would you bother using the spread syntax?

Comment: That's just the way the method usage is documented by Font Awesome. The edit by @juli seems like a more succinct and user friendly approach.

Answer (score 1):

`import` and `export` are defined to be statically analyzable, so they cannot depend on runtime information. Therefore, it is not possible with `import` statement.

The object looking like thing after import is called named imports that are used to get selected items from the list of exported items. For instance, fontawesome has all the icons objects exported via a single file. Now you can use import { ... } to import only the items you need.